# Access both register and login pages for anonimus MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

When user open my site, he sees login page (mentioned in routeConfig). But if he tries to access register page (or any other but it's normal), he still be redirected to login page. Both actions are [AllowAnonimus]. In my web config i have such a paragraph

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

I wish I could transfer to register page but not to others and I don't want to put [Authorize] to all actions.

Comment: I assume you mean `[AllowAnonymous]`

Comment: can you post your controller and action

Answer (score 0):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginController : Controller {}
```

Also you dont really need authentication mode = forms.

Add to webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>
```

And use your RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also use the global authentication filters:

```
 public class FilterConfig
 {
     public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
     {
         filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
         filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
      }
 }
```

This will allow [AllowAnonymous] to work all your controllers will need authorization or you can add authorization to just methods if needed.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Test() {}
```

Should mention if you dont want to add [AllowAnonymous] just leave the controller or method be.